# Timeout when deploying large model to Vertex AI endpoint

Tags: google-api-python-client

I'm trying to deploy my model to my Vertex AI endpoint, but I get this timeout:

```
endpoint._deploy_call(
  File "C:\Users\anna\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\tagscenarios-pliF7DGk-py3.10\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\aiplatform\models.py", line 1231, in _deploy_call
    operation_future.result()
  File "C:\Users\anna\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\tagscenarios-pliF7DGk-py3.10\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\future\polling.py", line 256, in result
    self._blocking_poll(timeout=timeout, retry=retry, polling=polling)
  File "C:\Users\anna\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\tagscenarios-pliF7DGk-py3.10\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\future\polling.py", line 139, in _blocking_poll
    raise concurrent.futures.TimeoutError(
concurrent.futures._base.TimeoutError: Operation did not complete within the designated timeout of 900 seconds.
```

I'm following this documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest

And try to deploy my model like this:

```
model = aiplatform.Model('/projects/my-project/locations/us-central1/models/{MODEL_ID}')

endpoint.deploy(model,
                min_replica_count=1,
                max_replica_count=5
                machine_type='n1-standard-4',
                accelerator_type='NVIDIA_TESLA_K80',
                accelerator_count=1)
```

My model is very large (close to 40GB), and I have no problems with this method when deploying smaller models.

It seems to be related to this issue, but the new version didn't fix this problem. https://github.com/googleapis/python-aiplatform/issues/1870

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, `google-cloud-aiplatform` does not allow to extend via api the timeout, so, incase you are using `google-cloud-aiplatform` (1.19.0)
what i found is i could set the default polling timeout to a higher value

though hacky, it does not have any risky side effects since it's done within an isolated kfp component

```
@component(
packages_to_install=["google-cloud-aiplatform", ..],
base_image=BASE_IMAGE,
)
def deploy(
  ...
):

  ...


from google.cloud import aiplatform

from google.api_core.future.polling import DEFAULT_POLLING

### Set the default timeoutto 3600 seconds
DEFAULT_POLLING._timeout = 3600

model = aiplatform.Model(...)
model.deploy(...)

  ...
```